# How do I install PHP intl extension on CentOS?

Tags: php, centos, installation, yum, php-extension

I know virtually nothing about installing packages. I managed to install Zend Framework 1 with yum a while back by following a very specific tutorial.

Now I need the PHP intl extension and I can't figure out how to install it.

I did

```
yum list php*intl
```

and saw that there was one available. So I did

```
yum install php-intl
```

and got the following error message:

```
Error: Package: php-intl-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
       Installed: php-common-5.3.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php-common = 5.3.17-2.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64 (base)
           php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I did not try the suggestions mentioned in the message because I didn't know what they would do and I am afraid of breaking something. This is a production machine and I don't have another machine to test on. I tried to find an rpm to download that was the same version as my PHP, but had no luck.

What do those two suggestions do and are they *safe* to try?
What else can I try to get the intl extension installed?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As you have php-commom from remi repositories, you need to get php-intl from remi also.

Add `--enable-repo` option as follows:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
```

Comment: I'm unable to test this because remi is now PHP 5.4 and I'm not ready to upgrade yet. But the answer makes total sense and I assume it would have given desired result when remi was still PHP 5.3.x.

Comment: You're right, I got the same error message but I've PHP 5.4

Comment: If you're using the "multiple versions" approach to the Remi repos, the command you want is `yum install php56-php-intl` (substitute in your selected version for `56`).

Answer (score 11):

If you have higher PHP version like 5.6, you have to enable both `remi` and `remi-php56` repos to install all the additional dependencies:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install php-intl
```

Comment: If you're using the "multiple versions" approach to the Remi repos, the command you want is `yum install php56-php-intl` (substitute in your selected version for `56`).

Answer (score 2):

I successfully installed INTL via pecl using following steps.

1) install icu & libs:

`yum -y install icu libicu libicu-devel`

2) php-devel package and phpize:

`yum -y install php-devel phpize`

3) and, of course gcc:

`yum -y install gcc gcc-cpp gcc-c++`

This is working for me.my php version is  5.6.12

Comment: Don"t use the PECL extension which is deprecated and outdated as now merged in php-src. all providers of PHP packages have it. If you can install php-devel, you can also install php-intl from the same source.

Comment: For centos 8 use dnf instead of yum

Answer (score 2):

for php 7.0 using

```
#list all options    
$ sudo yum list php7*intl

#install
$ sudo yum install php70-intl
```

Answer (score 1):

Yum is throwing an error because we are attempting to update multiple packages to versions that conflict. Your yum output says that php-intl requires a specific version of the php-common. Removing all the junk:

```
Requires 5.3.3-14
Installed 5.3.17-2
Available 1st Option: 5.3.3-3
Available 2nd Option: 5.3.3-14
```

This tells us that you already have installed a more recent version of php-common (5.3.17-2) than is allowed by php-intl.

I think you have two options. (As a newbie myself, I would not attempt these without practicing in a dev environment.)

## 1) Remove remi Packages

Quoting from a similar question on Super User. "Try removing all remi php packages, disable remi repository and install the default centos 6 php 5.3.3 packages."

https://superuser.com/questions/505340/centos-6-how-to-install-php-mysql-when-php-common-remi-is-present

## 2) Downgrade php-common to Version 5.3.3-14

```
yum downgrade php-common
```

I have no idea if you would run into more dependency issues and have to downgrade other packages. I found more details here.

https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=40567&forum=56

Other Stack Exchange sites show similar questions.

https://serverfault.com/search?q=centos+error+package (370 results)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=centos+error+package (57 results)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate just a little on [@Fernando Valler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7580823/fernando-valler)'s answer.

On my Fedora 35 machine, I have multiple installs of php. To check how many, I use a tool by Symfony (I am not sure how to do otherwise so quickly):

```
 $ symfony local:php:list
 +---------+--------------------------+---------+ 
 | Version |        Directory         |   PHP   |    
 +---------+--------------------------+---------+ 
 | 7.4.30  | /opt/remi/php74/root/usr | bin/php | 
 | 8.0.22  | /usr                     | bin/php |  
 | 8.1.10  | /opt/remi/php81/root/usr | bin/php |  
 +---------+--------------------------+---------+
```

Say I miss `intl` for version 8.1.10. First check whether `intl.so` is indeed not within its modules directory: `php81  -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');"`.

To install it, check packages by `dnf list php*intl`, you get something like:

```
$sudo dnf list php*intl
Installed Packages
php-intl.x86_64  8.0.22-1.fc35  @updates
Available Packages
php-intl.x86_64   8.0.23-1.fc35  updates 
php-symfony-intl.noarch  2.8.52-7.fc35  fedora  
php-symfony3-intl.noarch  3.4.49-2.fc35 fedora  
...
php72-php-intl.x86_64  7.2.34-11.fc35.remi  remi    
php81-php-intl.x86_64  8.1.10-1.fc35.remi  remi    
php82-php-intl.x86_64  8.2.0~rc2-15.fc35.remi  remi
```

Select what you need, say for `php8.1.10`, and install intl extension for it: `sudo dnf install  php81-php-intl`. It will pop  up within the modules directory for php 8.1.